# Orientation of screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

How do I make sure that the only orientations allowed are Portrait or Upside down portrait?

I made the change in the project settings, but I'm having trouble making the change in my GameViewController.

I need to make the change in this function:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```

However, the "UIInterfaceOrientationMask" structure doesn't have an option that only allows portrait and upside down portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow all orientations in the project settings, then only orientations allowed are Portrait or Upside down portrait in your viewController except the `GameViewController`:

```
// BaseViewController
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```

Finally in the `GameViewController`:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to use the "|" operator with .Portrait and .PortraitUpsideDown.

Comment: Trying to use `rawValue`

Comment: Thanks. Why do I have to use "UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue" instead of ".Portrait.rawValue" for the OR operation?

Comment: I think the `.Portrait.rawValue` works as well. Actually it depends on your return value type. It works on `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` not `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown)
```

Not sure if Swift will support a bitwise operator.