# How to auto rotate screen to landscape mode in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have so many UIViewController in my project but for specific UIViewController (not for all), I want to make auto rotate to its layout to landscape in viewDidLoad method. Please help me to solve.

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30836995/907422

Comment: follow this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6